# Removing duplicate column data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do something pretty simple on the face of it but I havent been able to and would love some help if possible.   I apologize for asking such a basic question but the answers I have found previously require visual basic and I dont quite have understanding to put that into effect.

I have two columns.   Column A is the company name and Column B which is the company name and also the address.   I just need to remove the company name from B and keep the address

Example:

```
The Aaron M. Priest Literary Agency | The Aaron M. Priest Literary Agency 708 Third Ave., 23rd Fl. New York, NY 10017
```

Desired format:

```
The Aaron M. Priest Literary Agency | 708 Third Ave., 23rd Fl. New York, NY 10017
```

Thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are talking about doing this in a database or in Excel.
In a database you could do something like the following

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ColB =ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING(COlB,len(ColA)+1,len(colb))))
```

You could improve it by checking for the space between the end of the agency name and address, checking the extact length etc but this will work.

If this an excel issue then if have ColA and ColB you could you create a new column, ColC and add the following formula

```
=MID(ColC,LEN(ColA)+1,LEN(ColB))
```

You would then have to copy this formula to against the columns you need.

Note in both case the +1 is to move the starting position forward form the last character of the agency name.

Comment: First, thank you for helping.  So what I am coming up with is this but I am getting a circular reference error.   It is in excel I am working.   My formula is this : =MID(C9,LEN(A9)+1,LEN(B9))

Comment: Instead of C9, there should be B9.

Comment: If the solution satisfies you, please tick "Accept", then everyone can see that the problem is solved already (and the answerer will get points).

Answer (score 1):

Formula in C2 = `"= TRIM(MID(B3;SEARCH(A3;B3) + LEN(A3);LEN(B3)-LEN(A3)))"`

OR if you use VBA try this function

```
Function CutTheSame(Cell1 As Range, Cell2 As Range)        
    Dim sC1 As String: sC1 = Cell1.Value
    Dim sC2 As String: sC2 = Cell2.Value
    Dim n As Integer: n = InStr(sC2, sC1)

    CutTheSame = Trim(Mid(sC2, n + Len(Trim(sC1))))        
End Function
```

and fill column C (test the result in C column) with the result from the function

The formula in cell `C2 is "= CutTheSame(A2 ; B2)"`

Comment: This was the output in column c when I applied the formula.   Not sure what I did wrong.  

A Management | A Management 12001 Ventura Pl., Ste. 340 Studio City, CA 91604 |aaaaaaaaaaamanagementmanagementmanagementmanagementmanagementmanagementmanagementmanagementmanagementmanagementmanagementmanagement

Comment: @user2444249: juri Ruut too .. sorry again .. wrong direction .. it's updated

Comment: @JüriRuut : Have you try this ?

Comment: @JüriRuut : sorry, but i didn't use lower or uppercase and there's no repeating spaces .. it's just mid() function implementation

Comment: The code here will be not too readable:
`Function MultipleSpacesRemoved(InputString As String) As String
     
      While InStr(InputString, "  ") > 0
        InputString = Replace(InputString, "  ", " ")
      Wend
     MultipleSpacesRemoved = InputString
     
    End Function`

Comment: Addition to your code: `Dim sC1 As String: sC1 = MultipleSpacesRemoved(Cell1.Value)
    Dim sC2 As String: sC2 = MultipleSpacesRemoved(Cell2.Value)`